# Select non registred values in MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, select

I have two tables in Mysql, Products and Inventory...

Products
int id_product
varchar name

Inventory
id_inventory
product_id
existence

So when my product '3' is out of stock I delete the row in Inventory where product_id = 3
And now I need to get all values that I have deleted on Inventory cause I need to make a report of missing products...

How can I make this query?

I used `SELECT i.* FROM inventory i, products p WHERE i.product_id!=p.id_product` but it doesn't works..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN would do as you wish as the rows you are looking for would have no corresponding row in inventory for a row in products, and so that gives the query ...

```
SELECT
    p.product_id
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN inventory i
ON i.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE i.product_id IS NULL
```

Alternatively you could simply just not delete the row from inventory when unavailable.  Just then do something like

```
SELECT
    p.product_id
FROM product p
INNER JOIN inventory i
ON i.product_id = p.product_id
AND i.quantityInStock = 0
```

Either way works

Answer (score 0):

or

```
select p.* from product p 
where not exists (select null from inventory i where i.product_id=p.id_product)
```